# How do I add an entry into the File Association preferences programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse Feature that provides the user with the ability to create projects.  The projects created will have a .pdf file as a one of the resources.

So, when my user double clicks this .pdf file resource, he currently receives an error that his file cannot be opened.

What I want to do is have my Eclipse Feature add the .pdf file in the File Associations and attempt to associate the file type with the users existing default pdf viewer the he/she may have installed on the PC.

Just like I did here using the Eclipse Preferences Dialog manually.

[image: Eclipse Preferences Dialog]

This Feature is not a widely used tool, and for reasons beyond my control, it is a Windows Only Feature.  Therefore solutions that encompass all the major operating systems isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` to define an editor and an associated file extension. If you use the `command` or `launcher` attributes of the extension point definition the editor will be assumed to be an external editor

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors"> 
  <editor 
     id="com.xyz.PDFEditor" 
     name="PDF editor" 
     icon="./icons/PDFEditor.png"
     extensions="pdf" 
     command="command to run" 
     default="true"> 
  </editor>
```

Comment: in the portion where you say, "If you use the command or launcher attributes of the extension point definition..."  it seems that you saying that I need to define a command or write a launcher that handles the logic of doing the work of figuring out how to open the external editor for the pdf file.  Is this true?  Or am I missing something that could be more simple than that?

Comment: 'command' is an external command to run, 'launcher' you have to write a launcher class.

Comment: You can use something like `Desktop.open` in a launcher to run the program associated with a PDF.

Comment: Very nice.  I went the launcher route and used the java.awt.Desktop class and called open on it with the file as a parameter, and it worked great.  Marking this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dug into this myself, but check out [Contributing content types](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/runtime_content_contributing.htm?cp=2_0_3_4_1) in the Eclipse help.